# EndpointNotFound exception on Silverlight Web App, hosted on IIS

Tags: wcf, silverlight

Once again I hope you can assist with a problem I can't figure out.

I have a Silverlight web app that used to work and after making changes to the code, adding some WCF methods and updating tables on an MS-SQL database, it has stopped working and I cannot figure out why.

The web app runs on Windows 7 hosted in the default IIS.

When running through Visual Studio it works fine, but not when running from the web page.

I know it has something to do with the Enpdoint, but what is strange is that I didn't change anything there. It runs from the same site on IIS.

The WCF trace:

```
Exception.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

I am not all that familiar with Silverlight so cannot figure out what has changed or what I broke.

A portion of Web.config:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="HSCGym.Web.GymRebateService.customBinding0" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00">
          <binaryMessageEncoding/>
          <httpTransport/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="HSCGym.Web.GymRebateService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="HSCGym.Web.GymRebateService.customBinding0" contract="HSCGym.Web.GymRebateService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

If I break and check the EndPoint Uri address, it shows incorrectly:

http://localhost:8080/rebate/ebate/GymRebateService.svc

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Neill

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you haven't told your web service where its end point is so it will use the one that you created it with which was most likely localhost.

Here is a bit of code I use to automatically switch between localhost and server so I don't have to remember to do it when deploying

```
string ServerPath = App.Current.Host.Source.AbsoluteUri.Replace(App.Current.Host.Source.AbsolutePath, "");
        string ServicePath = ServerPath + "/Services/YOURSERVICENAME.svc";

        var myBindings = new BasicHttpBinding();
        myBindings.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
        myBindings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
        var address = new EndpointAddress(ServicePath);

        App.GlobalVars.service = new RIFTRunComparerServiceClient(myBindings,address);
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. Where should I add this code. The last time I worked on this code I was using Windows 7 and and a lower version of Visual Studio. I'm now on Windows 8.1 and upgraded the project to Visual Studio 2013. Wonder if that could have caused an issue, because like I said, the only thing I did was add code to the service and make some visual changes to the page. The app runs on a local site, so I have always used localhost:8080/rebate/.....etc

Comment: Add this in where ever you make a new service reference i.e. just before you call it to do something.

Comment: App.GlobalVars.service = new RIFTRunComparerServiceClient(myBindings, address); - Both GlobalVars and RIFTRunComparerServiceClient - cannot resolve symbol. Any ideas?

Comment: They are types in my application so won't be in yours. You would replace those with the name of your web service reference that you have setup.

Comment: CommunicationException in reference.cs. The remote server returned an error: Not Found

Comment: Is there a service at that endpoint? Can you open up a browser window and go to that service.

Comment: Yes. Both through Visual Studio and loaded into IIS. If I run the app directly in a browser, I get the correct address now. http://localhost:8080/rebate/...etc, but my WCF calls are still not happening. I put in a simple meeage box after the call is supposed to complete. Never gets show. In Visual Studio it just tells me "The remote server returned an error: NotFound." I know this is a pretty generic error message, but doesn't help me in figuring out where the problem lies.

Comment: Think that was a problem in my web.config. Have a new issue now though. "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in HSCGym.Web.dll but was not handled in user code" Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Its like my Linq.dbml isn't initialized or something...

Comment: Nope. I now get the correct address to the Service, but my calls to the service are not doing anything....

Comment: Could be a problem with your actual web service code then. Try setting some break points and calling the web service.

Comment: I'd have to try to set up debugging from IIS again. Did it a while back. Like I say, it works perfectly fine debugging from Visual Studio. Doesn't work when deployed.

Comment: Marking this as correct because it lead my down the path to getting it to work. After setting up debugging, I got a nice error saying I didn't have access to the database. Had to add a user for IIS_APPPOOL\rebate to SQL and set the appropriate permissions. Then all was good. And the method of settings for debug or release is cool too. Thanks Kevin. Appreciate it loads. Neill